# How to declare a RPM as being a subset of another RPM?

Tags: package, rpm

I have a RPM X.rpm. A user need only one bit of this RPM and therefore I prepare a new RPM X-subpart.rpm.

Is there a way to specify in the spec file that X-subpart is a subset of X and therefore doesn't need to be installed if X is already installed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to let the "big one" provide the same symbol as the "small one", or its name. Then you can depend on this symbol and get them both.

You can even depend on a file path which is a condition fulfilled by both RPMs.

See [here](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-depend-manual-dependencies.html).

Comment: Ok, I will try that. Something like: X.rpm provides X-sub and X-subpart provides X-sub, then another RPM (Y) depends on X-sub and if X is installed it will not install X-subpart. Now, if neither X nor X-sub is installed, which one will be pulled when installing Y?

Comment: @Barth That's right. For the latter question, I don't exactly know which one will be installed; that probably depends on the package manager used (zypper, smart etc.) Graphical tools might ask you which one to use...